# Java null pointer exception on if statement

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have following if statement:

```
if (node.left.left == null && node.left.right != null)
```

Related to a binary tree. Before this if statement I have a other if statement that checks if node.left is null.

Why am I getting null pointer exception on this statement?

Full code in the method up until the exception:

```
 BinaryTreeNode node= root;


if (root==null)
    return true;
else
    {
        while(node!=null)
        {
        if (node.key>key && node.left !=null)
        {
            if (node.left.key==key)
                {
                    if(node.left.left==null && node.left.right==null)
                        node.left=null;
                    if(node.left.left==null && node.left.right!=null)
                        node.left=node.left.right;
```

Comment: Could you show us the exact error message and your `node.left` check? My guess is that the check doesn't work out.

Comment: Show both statements, not just one of them. Also, please make this a MCVE; as is we have no way to try it ourselves.

Answer (score 4):

```
                    node.left=null;
                if(node.left.left==null && node.left.right!=null)
                    node.left=node.left.right
```

You are *explicitly* setting node.left to null.